# How to stop applications without focus from opening popup windows

Tags: desktop-environments, focus

Sometimes when one is using any app, almost at the moment when one is going to click or push key "enter", a window appears in a "pop-up style" related to another app (example : dialog of updates) and with all the momentum in the fingers, one finishes pushing "accept" over the popup window and not the planned app. Most cases are not critical, but they can consume some of time.

Is there some home-made or professional solution for this?

Comment: For update manager see [How to disable the update manager popup?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/218755/how-to-disable-the-update-manager-popup)

Comment: I'm sure some moderator or admin changed the title of the subject from"heartless emergent dialogs at high speed ready to be pushed not web browser popups"

to

"How to stop applications without focus from opening popup windows"

Then i googled the modified title and the third result in the search was this page :

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windowsxp/ht/stealingfocus02.htm

page about "How To Prevent Programs From Stealing Focus in Windows"

....and now i can search more easily.

I'm going to look the update-manager issue too, thanks.

Comment: Also see [Prevent Windows from stealing focus](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8494/prevent-windows-from-stealing-focus?rq=1)