# Tomboy doesn't open notes from the tray - sends to the launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, tomboy

When I click on any Tomboy notes listed in Unity tray it sends me to the launcher where the Tomboy icon starts shaking and the note opens only after I click on the icon in the launcher. I need to open it with the single click on the list in the tray, how to do that? Previously I didn't have such problem. Ubuntu 14.04, Unity.

[image]

Comment: All I can say is that it works here (14.04) like it used to work in your case. It must be something on your system. What I don't understand: what has the image to do with the question :)??

Comment: The image shows my screen after I click on any Tomboy note in the tray above. To open a note I need to click twice - on the tray and then on the launcher. I want to open it with a single click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always had this same issue with Tomboy, but lowering the Focus and Raise behavior in CompizConfig fixes it. First install compizconfig-settings-manager:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Run it with:

```
ccsm
```

Then navigate to General / Focus & Raise Behavior.

By default the [Focus Prevention Level](http://wiki.compiz.org/GeneralOptions#Focus_.26_Raise_Behaviour) is set to Low and Tomboy always opens up behind other windows. If I change it to off, Tomboy opens up in front of other windows.

This may have other ramifications (other Windows may begin to steal focus, etc). You can set exceptions in this same settings panel.

Credit to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8494/prevent-windows-from-stealing-focus) that I used originally to solve this.

Comment: You should detail the solution that you have as well as providing the link.

Comment: @gman Updated it to include a summary of the solution

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, Mark H.! It solved the issue I have been annoyed by for a long time. Another side of it was the similar troubles with the message icon in the tray. Whenever new letters would come the message icon becomes blue, but when I click on it Thunderbird would not open but instead shake in the launcher. Now it also works. Thank you!

Comment: @brijabasi Glad to have helped! If you're all set please mark the answer as correct

Comment: @MarkH. Done that!