# Always on focus window

Tags: focus

Is there a way to get a windows always on focus?

I mean not just on top, but with the focus on it if another window pops up on the screen.

Comment: It could be, but I've tried without success. I'll try again and I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Yup! This is fairly simple to do.</strike>

All you have to do is right-click on the title bar and select **Always On Top**:

[image]

You can also make it *always* show no matter what desktop you're on (if you have multiple desktops enabled) by selecting **Always on Visible Workspace**:

[image]

**EDIT**: This doesn't actually keep the window in focus when a new window opens. I'll look into this a bit more.

Comment: @alextoind Look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8494/prevent-windows-from-stealing-focus). Looks like a duplicate of your question :)